# Can Bar charts and pie charts be drawn using npm's module flotjs?

Tags: javascript, npm, flot

Have imported flotjs npm module in the existing application and and made a simple line char. Now want to use the same in drawing pie chart, bar chart , multi-line chart, etc. Googled for the same on the web but still limited to results. Is there any proper link with examples to achieve the same ? Links referred [[Link1]](http://www.pikemere.co.uk/blog/tutorial-flot-how-to-create-bar-charts/) [Link](http://www.flotcharts.org/)

Comment: idk but you can check out https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Tutorials

Comment: Thanks, but not using d3 library.